# Michael Hart's Rails Tutorial: undefined local variable or method 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, local-variables

I am at the end of section 9.4.3, after changing the header links when you are signed in and signed out. When I try to load any page I receive the same error:

```
Showing C:/Sites/sample_app/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #7 raised:
undefined local variable or method `id' for #<Class:0x5cbd658>

Extracted source (around line #7):
4:  <nav class="round">
5:      <ul>
6:          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
7:          <% if signed_in? %>
8:              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
9:          <% end %>
10:             <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Sites/sample_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
app/models/user.rb:47:in `authenticate_with_salt'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:26:in `user_from_remember_token'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:12:in `current_user'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:16:in `signed_in?'
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__376347676_36919992'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___333215577_32850792'
```

Here is my sessions_helper.rb file:

```
module SessionsHelper
def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    current_user = nil
end

private
    def user_from_remember_token
        User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
    end

    def remember_token
        cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
    end
end
```

I have also checked my code with what is on [Github](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app) but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please show us your `User` model, around line 47.

Comment: Here is my user.rb file: http://pastebin.com/Jw409Uah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just made a copy-paste error. Line 46 of your `user.rb` should read:

```
def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
  user = find_by_id(id)
  (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
end
```

The parameters you use are from the `User.authenticate` class method.

(Also, please don't use tabs, it's bad Ruby style.)

Comment: You're right, I passed the wrong parameter names to that function. Thanks!